# jsf valuechangelistener not firing on checkbox deselect

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a primefaces checkbox on a form with a valuechangelistener. The backing bean method gets called on checkbox select, but doesn't get called on deselect.

I'm using the same technique with almost identical code elsewhere in my application and it works fine on both select and deselect.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{shareoutSlip.processed}" 
                              valueChangeListener="#{orderFormBean.handleShareoutSlipProcessed}" >
    <p:ajax />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Here is the valueChangeListener method (all it does for now is print a message to the console):

```
public void handleShareoutSlipProcessed(ValueChangeEvent vcEvent) {
    logger.info("Shareout Slip Processed");
}
```

Is there anything else on my form that could be interfering with the method being called on checkbox deselect? I've put a h:messages tag on the form but I'm not seeing any validation messages.

Comment: Tried using the listener on the ajax tag instead of the valueChangeListener? And what are your JSF version and imple and the PF version?

Comment: I'm using JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces 6.1 implemented on Tomcat 8. Thanks for your idea. I'll look up how to attach the listener to the ajax tag as you suggest. It's very strange that the technique should work on one page ok, but not on this page. The different handlers have the same signature and are in the same bean! This is one of the reasons I'm getting out of JSF as I encounter 'voodoo' like this all the time.

Comment: remarkable that you encounter voodoo and I don't... valuechangelisteners are rarely needed in modern times.  I shortly tried one of the hyped JavaScript frameworks but it required waaaay to much additional code to achieve the same functionality. including lots of javascript validation security etc for serious business2business applications

Comment: And if you don't post actual [mcve] it is hard for us to even try to reproduce. And if it works in a what is in your mind a100% identical other situation, then there are two possible causes: 1: they are not 100% identical, 2: the code that is actually running is not the code that you think is running (deploy problem). Both are actually not something JSF can do something about...

Comment: And you state in your question: **ALMOST** identical... Then what are the differences? Having a different component is not 'almost' identical... but a major difference...

Comment: And there might simply be a bug in one of the components... It is humans developing them ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The difference between the 2 handler methods is their method names; the handler methods are in the same bean and the method signatures are the same i.e. public void method-name(ValueChangeEvent vcEvent) { }. I can change the code in each to a simple console output message. One gets called on checkbox select AND deselect, the other gets called on select only. The main difference is that the checkboxes are in different views. The view is large and complex so I can't post it all here. I will try to create a M, C and V example as you advise.

Comment: Any progress???

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call this method inside `p:ajax` tag?

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{shareoutSlip.processed}">
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{orderFormBean.handleShareoutSlipProcessed}" />
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: That is what I stated in my first comment

Comment: Sorry, I just saw you forgot event="change"